# How to Create FileStreame from byte[]?

Tags: c#, wpf, filestream

I have a class like this:

```cs
class person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public byte[] PersonImage{get;set;}
}
```

When I Load my Person From DataBase I want to show PersonImage in a Image control, so I want to create BitmapImage from my byte[]:

```cs
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

bitmapImage.BeginInit();
var filestream = new MemoryStream(PersonImage);
bitmapImage.StreamSource = filestream;

bitmapImage.EndInit();// I have Exception in this line
```

My Exception is:

> No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.

--edite
my Inner Exception is :

> Inner Exception:Exception from HRESULT:0*88982F50

Comment: Have you looked at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886849/error-in-my-byte-to-wpf-bitmapimage-conversion - it may help (how the questioner does their byte to image stream conversion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new FileStream out of a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076192/create-new-filestream-out-of-a-byte-array)

Comment: You'd better take a look at the code that wrote the data into the dbase as well.  This question isn't otherwise answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `PersonImage` is really a valid `byte[]` representing an image try

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

bitmapImage.BeginInit();
var somestream = new MemoryStream(PersonImage);
somestream.Position = 0; // "rewind" stream to start...
bitmapImage.StreamSource = somestream;

bitmapImage.EndInit();
```

Comment: @mtaboy that means that `PersonImage` very probably does not contain a valid image... you need to check what `PersonImage` contains

Answer (score 0):

Your image is probably not a supported format. Try the following method:

```
public BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
    using (MemoryStream convertedImageStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();

        image.Save(convertedImageStream, ImageFormat.Png);

        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.StreamSouce = convertedImageStream;

        bitMapImage.EndInit();
    }

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Make sure you include the following using statements at the top of your file:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```