# C# BinaryWrite adding nulls to the file

Tags: c#, file-io

I have some data in a byte array, which are characters that have to be written to a file. The file is a input to another tool so the format has to be as specified.

The format that should appear in the file looks like this
    2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 T
    0
    3 1 
    12
    1 1 1 F
    14 12 T

I am using the following code to write a byte array to file. covData in the code is a byte array.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        foreach (byte b in covData)
        {
            Console.Write((char)b);
            bw.Write(b);
        }
    }
}
```

If I now open the file with a Hex editor, there are extra nulls in front of the data which is in the byte that I am writing to.

Eg.
00 00 32 20 00 00 31 20 00 00 31 20 00 00 31 20

Why are the first two nulls (00 00) appearing when the first byte contains 2, which appears as the third bit of data (32)? The next data is a space (20) appears correctly next to it but then there is another pair for nulls after that. Is there a way to stop the nulls being written to the file?

Comment: Not an answer, but is there a reason why you're using a `BinaryWriter` to output *text*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems very complicated. Why don't you just do:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, covData);
```

Comment: I had written that initially however I still had the same output with the extra nulls. I then tried explicitly using a BinaryWriter and used foreach to write out each byte to check the information in the byte array.

Comment: @pdepala Then I guess your byte array is wrong. Can you post a minimal example of a byte array not properly written to file?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The byte array must have extra spaces. Populating the covData array with Array Initialization with the data as expected writes the information to the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should read it all into a byte array and then I'd recommend the use of a `MemoryStream` to decompress it.

```
byte[] compressedBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

using (var mstrm = new MemoryStream(compressedBytes))
{
    using(var inStream = new GzipStream(mstrm, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (var outStream = File.Create("outputfilename"))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) != 0)
            {
                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }  

        }
    }
}
```

Code taken from: [Create new FileStream out of a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076192/create-new-filestream-out-of-a-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood exactly why the issue happened was but filtering the buffer array, like below got rid of the extra nulls.

```
if (b != default(Byte))
{
    Console.WriteLine((byte)b);
    bw.Write(b);
}
```